# Create Patterns in Phraselist that Cortana can understand

Tags: uwp, windows-10, text-to-speech, voice-recognition, cortana

I'm working on an UWP app which should filter cars by their VehicleIdentificationNumber (VIN). This VIN is a  17-char long string. It can include Numbers and letters on every position.

Do anyone has an idea, how i can let the User dictate this 17-char long string and Cortana will understand this correctly? Some tests showed that Cortana understands sometime the digits, and in a second try she writes it out as "three" f. e.

This are the lines in my VCD-File, which than calls a Background Service. In the BackgroundService the Result i get out of VehicleIdentificationNumber is "...".

```
<Command Name="selectedSpecificVehicleByVIN">
  <Example>Fahrzeug nach VIN WAUZZZ8V5EA012963 filtern</Example>
  <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase">Fahrzeug nach VIN {VehicleIdentificationNumber} filtern</ListenFor>
  <Feedback>Suche nach Fahrzeug mit VIN {VehicleIdentificationNumber}</Feedback>
  <VoiceCommandService Target="VehicleSelectionService"/>
</Command>
```

And my PhraseTopic looks like this:

```
<PhraseTopic Label="VehicleIdentificationNumber" Scenario="Dictation" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an answer for this case. 
It was quite simple. I only had to add two subjects to my PhraseTopic.

```
 <PhraseTopic Label="VehicleIdentificationNumber" Scenario="Dictation">
  <Subject>Characters</Subject>
  <Subject>Alphabet</Subject>
</PhraseTopic>
```

One small problem is, that Cortana adds some whitespaces inside the spelled VIN. This can be removed with simple string operations.

Hope I can help somebody, who has the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, the "Dictation" scenario didn't have any documentation when I last looked.  This will help my own app out considerably.

Answer (score 1):

I had to write a parser that would take the string response that you are provided and convert the number text to digits.  If you're doing one digit at a time, it shouldn't be too bad.

You could also try to create a target for each digit/letter since most people would speak them separately.  Then, instead of using a PhraseTopic, use a Phraselist and put each digit and letter in the list.

Comment: I tested your second advice. For information: It isn't working if i use PhraseList and put each digit/letter inside, because in the VCD only the first occured item will be used every time. 
So if i create this PhraseList like <PhraseList Label="Vin"><Item>A </Item><Item>B</Item>... </PhraseList> and my saying VIN is WVWxxxxx.. it will take the W on every position and will search for VIN "WWWWWWWWWWWWWW". 
And if i make for each Digit a separate Phraselist, the amount of Phraselist per Commandset is longer than 10. 

I will check your first advice if it'll works.